# SQL: How to set multiple conditions using instead of using a bunch of ORs?

Tags: sql, where-clause

So, this is incredibly simple, but I just cannot process how to do it. The following code works.

```
where OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus = 7
or OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus = 3
or OH.SalesRepID = 148 and oh.OrderStatus = 1
```

But. I'm 90% sure there's an easier way. Something like

`where OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus = 7 or 3 or 1`

Obviously the above code doesn't work, but is there something like it? Thanks!

Comment: AND goes before OR. I.e. you are now doing `where (OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus = 7) or OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus = 3
or OH.SalesRepID = 148 and oh.OrderStatus = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `IN` operator

```
where OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus in (7, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IN operator. `OH.SalesRepID = 148 and OH.OrderStatus in (7, 3, 1)`